# String split with regex gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm trying to split my string that represents html markup so that `<ul>` tags end up as a separate index in the resulting array. I've created the following regex which seems to work for finding `<ul>...</ul>`:

```
/(<ul>.*?<\/ul>)/i
```

I know it works because I tested it here: https://regex101.com/r/DNAHzr/2

However, as seen in the snipped below, the string `split()` doesn't seem to actually split my markdown on the given regex:

```js
var body = "soupp\n\nWhat a bloody nice video!! :)) {{youtube:hyYnAioXOqQ}}\n\nSuppp\n\n<ul>\n<li>1\n</li>\n<li><b>2</b>\n</li>\n</ul>\n{{attachment:2938222}}\n\n<ul>\n<li>1\n</li>\n<li>2\n</li>\n</ul>\n<ol>\n<li>bruhh\n</li>\n<li>twotwo\n</li>\n</ol>"

var comps = body.split(/(<ul>.*?<\/ul>)/i).filter(x => !!x);

console.log(comps);
```

Can anybody help me get my method to work properly?

Comment: Remove the new-lines.

Comment: I actually need the newlines in the rest of the markdown which is why I'm trying to split off the `<ul>` tags and remove the newlines inside of those.

Comment: More relevant than ever: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7051394

Comment: @Rightleg I think the answer directly below that one is most appropriate here: "While it is true that asking regexes to parse arbitrary HTML is like asking a beginner to write an operating system, it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML.": https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/3874623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want something like this:

```
[ 'soupp\n\nWhat a bloody nice video!! :)) {{youtube:hyYnAioXOqQ}}\n\nSuppp\n\n',
'<ul>',
'\n<li>1\n</li>\n<li><b>2</b>\n</li>\n',
'</ul>',
'\n{{attachment:2938222}}\n\n',
'<ul>',
'\n<li>1\n</li>\n<li>2\n</li>\n',
'</ul>',
'\n<ol>\n<li>bruhh\n</li>\n<li>twotwo\n</li>\n</ol>' ]
```

Is that right?

If so, you should be able to simply use:

```
var comps = body.split(/(<.?ul>)/g);
```

EDIT:
To include the text and the `ul` tags, you need to match newlines, which `.*` won't. You can do it with:

```
var comps = body.split(/(<ul>[\s\S]*?<\/ul>)/g);
```

Which should give you:

```
[ 'soupp\n\nWhat a bloody nice video!! :)) {{youtube:hyYnAioXOqQ}}\n\nSuppp\n\n',
'<ul>\n<li>1\n</li>\n<li><b>2</b>\n</li>\n</ul>',
'\n{{attachment:2938222}}\n\n',
'<ul>\n<li>1\n</li>\n<li>2\n</li>\n</ul>',
'\n<ol>\n<li>bruhh\n</li>\n<li>twotwo\n</li>\n</ol>' ]
```

Comment: I actually want the `<ul>` and `</ul>` in the same string with its content

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant by : '<ul> tags end up as a separate index in the resulting array. '